# Unable to enable Gnome system wide extension for QT Application (version GNOME Shell 40.10)

Tags: qt, gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I am using a QT application which also shows an icon over panel but with latest gnome update the icon does not appear anymore. To show the notification icon, i’m trying to install and enable the extension : appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com

I’m using https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/extensions-enable.html.en to enable the system wide extension
After the extension is installed under /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions, I’m using the following command to enable it :
gnome-extensions enable appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com

Output of the command:
[Screenshot of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVyOY.png)

Note: This happened only after upgrading the gnome shell version to 40.10
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Same with version 42.5. Did you find any solution? Current user folder (~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions) works fine but system-wide folder (/usr/share/gnome-shell/extension) does not work anymore.